# How to track a android tablet in the same network using MAC address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, android, tracing

I lost my tablet , but I can see that the tablet is connected to the network on my router: [image]So I know the MAC address but I am unable to trace my tablet using this information and I am running out of time before the battery drains. I suspect it is stolen but at some distance as the signal quality shown is 17% while other devices show above 50%, from this I suspect it is either gone deep down something or is far away but still in the network.

So how to track this device with MAC XX...BE:FB? I also get the IP adress of the tablet from the router but the PING to that IP does not return any response and is blocking i.e not returning to command prompt. Now the signal has reduced to 8% as shown in router, I suspect that the tablet is in standby power saving mode where does not allow much network i\o.

Comment: Android have [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager). Can you use that to make the tablet make some sounds so you can locate it?

Comment: @Darius Wow , you made my day! I found it using this! Please write it as an answer, we were about to lodge a police complaint as I was unable to find it since yesterday, found that it had fallen in some furniture.

Comment: Please write it as an answer, we were about to lodge a police complaint as I was unable to find it since yesterday, found that it had fallen in some furniture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android have [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager). Assuming you are logged into the tablet (and the tablet has some internet connectivity), you can use it to locate your misplaced devices.

Comment: I also found that my other  device which was stolen a month back located near some spot where i live not much far away, the ADM causes message to be displayed on the tracked device , which is why I see that the thief has now has turned the location access off\switched off the phone and is showing : "Your device's location access is turned off"

Comment: so how can I get to know which SIM card has been installed on that phone as I see the ADM has shared the location and possibly other details like SIM card number etc

Comment: my new question based on this :https://superuser.com/questions/895609/using-android-device-manager-to-get-the-sim-details-of-located-device